# I want to use different server for webmail and different server for website with same domain. How can I do this?

Tags: email, dns, webserver, mx-record

I am trying to change the server for hosting my website and want to use the old server for webmail.

Old Domain: [www.oldServer.com](http://www.oldServer.com) IP example: 192.168.0.1
New Domain: [www.newServer.com](http://www.newServer.com) IP example: 192.168.0.15

Webmail should be available via office@oldServer.com but running on the old server with IP Adress 192.168.0.1.

I tried to change the A record of the oldServer and put in the new IP adress:
newServer 192.168.0.15 and changed the MX10 record to mail.newServer.com.

Additionally I changed another A record for mail:
mail.newServer.com. with new IP Adress 192.168.0.15

My goal is, as I mentioned, that the domain is the same (for example [www.exampleDomain.com](http://www.exampleDomain.com)) but should be provided by a new host. The email should be still available via the old host, but should also use the same name as the exampleDomain (office@exampleDomain).

The configuration above didn´t work and I still don´t know why. Can anyone help me out? What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple hosts in a single domain is fine, you just need to register both hosts on your DNS with different hostnames and IP address. Just make sure  to register the A records and MX record correctly.

What you are missing is the configuration of the webmail. You must also change the IP address and assign the default domain name for your email (smtp) or postoffice.